# eliminar TODOS los elementos de un array despues de index

Tags: java, array

Tengo el siguiente Array:

```
String [] array={"Hola", "mundo", "de", "Stack", "Overflow"};
```

Me gustaría eliminar los elementos del `array` que están después de un `index`, en este caso 2
Resultado:  `{"Hola", "mundo"}`

Esto significa que pasaría de un `array` `String[5]` a `String[2]`

¿Existe alguna función de alguna clase que haga esto?

Algo como:

```
array = ArrayUtils.removeAllElementsAfter(array, 2);
```

---

Se que se puede hacer una alternativa con ArrayList

**Alternativa con ArrayList:**

Pasar `Array` a `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList <String> arraylist = new ArrayList <String> (Arrays.asList(array));
```

Borrar todos elementos que estén desde el `index`(2) hasta el final

```
arraylist.subList(2, arraylist.size()).clear();
```

Volver a pasar el `ArrayList` a `Array`:

```
String[] array2 = arraylist.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: ¿Quieres quedarte con un array de igual longitud pero con los elementos en valor por defecto, o con un array con n elementos menos?

Comment: @DavidDPG Con menos elementos de `[5]` a `[2]`, edito la pregunta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay algo más fácil y rápido:

```
String[] array={"Hola", "mundo", "de", "Stack", "Overflow"};
String[] newarray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, 2);
```

Si el array no tiene `n` length `{"Hola"}` y no se quiere que se rellene con valores `null`:

```
String[] newarray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, (array.length < 2 ? array.length : 2));
```

De la documentación:

> Copies the specified range of the specified array into a new array.The
>   initial index of the range (from) must lie between zeroand
>   original.length, inclusive. The value at original[from] is placed into
>   the initial element of the copy(unless from == original.length or from
>   == to).Values from subsequent elements in the original array are placed intosubsequent elements in the copy. The final index of the
>   range(to), which must be greater than or equal to from,may be greater
>   than original.length, in which case null is placed in all elements of
>   the copy whose index isgreater than or equal to original.length -
>   from. The lengthof the returned array will be to - from.
>
> The resulting array is of exactly the same class as the original
>   array.

Hago un intento de traducción. Si alguien ve algún fallo que lo edite, que mi inglés es ordinario.

> Copia el rango especificado del array especificado en un nuevo array.
>   El índice inicial del rango (from) debe estar entre cero y
>   original.length, inclusive. El valor del original[from] se ubica en el
>   elemento inicial de copy (a no ser que from == original.length o from
>   == to). Valores de los elementos subsecuentes del array original se ubican en los elementos subsecuentes de copy. El índice final del
>   rango (to), que debe ser mayor que o igual a from, puede ser mayor que
>   original.length y en este caso en los elementos de copy con índice
>   mayor o igual a original.length - from se colocan valores null. La
>   longitud del array resultante será hasta - from.
>
> El array resultante es de exactamente la misma clase que el original.

Y con mis palabras pero más corto:

> `Arrays.copyOfRange(original, from, to)` devuelve una copia de los
>   elementos del array original en el rango *from* (inclusive) - *to*
>   (exclusive). El valor de *to* puede ser mayor que la longitud del array original. En este caso el array resultante se rellena con valores null para los índices superiores de la longitud del array original. El array resultante es del mismo tipo que el original.

Comment: Tiene muy buena pinta, parece justo lo que buscaba! Si es posible traduce la parte de la documentación o explicalo con tus palabras para que mas gente lo pueda entender, puesto que estamos es StackOverflowEs. Cuando lo hagas mencionarme con @ y la marco como aceptada y la voto! Muchas gracias!