# devolver un Array en java

Tags: java, array

Me gustaría crear una función en un programa que estoy haciendo, la cual me gustaría que me devolviera las un array de **los 5 primeros coches** del array y en caso de que hayan menos de 5 devuelva el máximo de coches que hay, había pensado algo asi :

```
public Car[] getCars() {

String[] Garage= new String[] {"Elem1", "Elem2", "Elem3","Elem4", "Elem5"};

}
```

¿Alguna ayuda? Gracias.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [eliminar TODOS los elementos de un array despues de index](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/271460/eliminar-todos-los-elementos-de-un-array-despues-de-index)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes valerte de **[`Arrays.copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(T[],%20int,%20int))** para crear un método que sea posible utilizar para cualquier cantidad de objetos límite. Así, si en un escenario se requieren como máximo `5` o como máximo `25` no tendrías que cambiar nada.

Por ejemplo:

```
public Car[] getPartialCars(int mLimit) {
    /*Aquí asumimos que arrayOfCars es un array de objetos del tipo Car*/
    //Determinamos el tamaño del array
    mSize=arrayOfCars.size();
    //Verificamos si es menor al límite requerido al llamar al método
    if (mSize < mLimit) {
        return arrayOfCars;
    } else {
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(arrayOfCars, 0, mLimit);
    }
}
```

Este método serviría para un contexto en que se necesiten como máximo `5`:

```
getPartialCars(5);
```

Y este cuando se necesiten como máximo `25`:

```
getPartialCars(25);
```

O cualquier otro valor. Lo único que cambia es el valor que le pasas al método al llamarlo.

Además, dado que `copyOfRange` admite también que se le indique a partir de dónde empezar, el método se puede ampliar si se quiere empezar desde una posición determinada, tomando las precauciones de errores del tipo *`Out of Bound`*